# SSIS Package will not import to MSDB after making 'EncryptSensitiveWithPassword'

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, ssms

I have an SSIS package that executes a handful of sql scripts and writes them to text files. The SSIS package imports just fine to MSDB when I use 'EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey', but as soon as I change it to 'EncryptSensitiveWithPassword' I get error in the attached image. I am using Visual Studio 2015 to develop the package and SSMS 2016. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is because to have it imported one needs to be decrypted by providing the password you can not supply by the method of deployment you use.

First of all, it is advisable to not to use the password protected deployments because you leak the actual password. The suggested method is "Rely on Server".

Lastly, if you insist you want to deploy it as desired, then use the Deployment Manifest or `dtutil.exe`

Comment: I was curious about this question and after reading your reply, I did a dummy deployment to my dev DB. I noticed that the exact error happens when a wrong password is supplied during export from msdb package store. It's been a long time using this deployment model.